# nginx proxy_pass upstream replace with variables

Tags: nginx

my upstream:

```
upstream upstream_**uba1**_console_f485c00e45256742e2cc641db834b150 {
    ip_hash;
    server 192.30.56.172:39443;
    check interval=2000 rise=1 fall=3 timeout=3000;
}

upstream upstream_**uba2**_console_f485c00e45256742e2cc641db834b150 {
    ip_hash;
    server 192.30.56.173:39443;
    check interval=2000 rise=1 fall=3 timeout=3000;
}
```

my location:

```
location  /opsuba/ {
    if ($args ~* region=(\w+?)(&|$)) {
       set $region $1;
    }
    limit_req zone=reqconsole burst=10000 nodelay;
    limit_conn connconsole 1000;
    **proxy_pass https://upstream_${region}_console_f485c00e45256742e2cc641db834b150;**
    include error_page_exclude_ajax.conf;
    include static_file.conf;
    access_log off;
}
```

how can i make `upstream_${region}_console_f485c00e45256742e2cc641db834b150` replace with variables?

Answer (score 0):

You specify the variable like `$1` (from regexp) or `$region` from the `set` command.
This should work in your config:

```
proxy_pass http://upstream_$region_console_f485c00e45256742e2cc641db834b150;
```

I've just tested it with this example config:

```
upstream upstream_uba1_console_f485c00e45256742e2cc641db834b150 { ip_hash; server 127.0.0.1:39443; }
upstream upstream_uba2_console_f485c00e45256742e2cc641db834b150 { ip_hash; server 127.0.0.1:39444; }

server {
    listen       80;
    location ~ ^/([^\/]*) {
        proxy_pass http://upstream_$1_console_f485c00e45256742e2cc641db834b150;
    }
}
server {
        listen 39443;
        root /var/www/;
        location / {
                try_files /url1.html $uri;
        }
}
server {
        listen 39444;
        root /var/www/;
        location / {
                try_files /url2.html $uri;
        }
}
```

Files on the filesystem:

```
/var/www/url1.html -> content url 1
/var/www/url2.html -> content url 2
```

Access through:

```
http://localhost/uba1/ -> url1.html
http://localhost/uba2/ -> url2.html
```

I did everything with local backends but will work with yours too.
Also I had to remove some params from your `upstream` block to make it work.